# What is the best way to check if file has changed in Bash and keep 15 last copies of it?

Tags: linux, bash, backup

What would be the best way to write a bash script and run it from `cron` (every hour) that:

1. Would see if a file in a directory has changed
2. If changed, make a copy with incrementing version number and date
   appended to filename
3. Keep last 15 versions of the file in the directory and delete the
   ones above 15th

I kind of feel I could have a go at it, but this one is important for me so I would be very glad to have opinion from others as I don't know shell scripting that well. I use mostly Debian and fedora.

Comment: Just use a version control system. Really.

Comment: Do you mean to run version control system as a cron job? Which one would be the simplest to use?

Comment: Being the "simplest to use" is subjective and personal -- I'm a [git](http://git-scm.com/) fan. It should be pretty simple to do in git (without ever touching cron) -- just run inotifywait on the file you want to watch, and then commit every time it changes. After every change, you squash anything over the last 15 changes.

Comment: I have used git a little too. So it will work equally well on binary files, right? Mine are encrypted files of small size.

Comment: If they aren't huge, sure. Binary deltas in git are fairly fast nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use rsnapshot, that gives you the possibility of make the rotate of a filesystem (or folders) and maintain an arbitraty number of versions.

Rsnapshot makes a freeze of the whole filesystem or folders, but with a little work you can delete old consecutive versions with no changes.

Rsnapshot uses rsync and has a lot of parameters for tuning. Obviously, it can be inserted in a crontab.

Answer (score 0):

It's called [newsyslog](https://www.mirbsd.org/man8/newsyslog) or [logrotate](http://man.cx/logrotate). This is the easiest way, saves you explicitly editing `crontab` and running other processes, and deals with the common pitfalls (like checking for old files, removing them, renaming the others, atomicity, etc.) already. It's proven, and used by the rest of the system, so you should reuse it.

Comment: How would I use it for one specific file though and would it have to be done through changing system log settings?

Comment: You just place the config for your specific file into, for example (on Debian) `/etc/logrotate.d/`. Or you can call [`logrotate`](http://man.cx/logrotate) manually with the config file, this doesn’t even need root.